# find an orthogonal basis for the space of solutions of the following equations

Tags: orthogonal-matrices

Q.find an orthogonal basis for the space of solutions of the following equations
2x+y-z=0 
y+z=0

How select solution? And how solve this question? ?

Comment: Do you know how to find the space of solutions of that pair of equations?

Answer (score 1):

As I see, you have a intersection of two plans which is the solution of $\{2x+y-z=0,~y+z=0\}$. First solve it to find the solution: $$X= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
z \\
-z \\
z  \end{array} \right)=z\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 \\
-1 \\
1  \end{array} \right)$$ Now you have a requested vector.

Comment: In this question,  solution basis and w

Comment: In this question, the basis has just one element because the space of solutions is just a line.